# How to call app script web app using ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-apps-script, web-applications

I wrote one script to count my google form response but not able to call that function remotely through ajax call. It shows me some error

> MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

```
$.getJSON('app script url', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Firstly, you've not asked a question here, just described a problem you have. Secondly, I'm not sure what help you're expecting anyone to provide without showing us your code.

Comment: It just that want to know ajax call of google appscript web app

Comment: This is sample code
$.getJSON('app script url', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });

Comment: That's the kind of information which should be in the question. Well judging from the error, the response is HTML, so don't use `$.getJSON`. Use `$.ajax()` instead.

Comment: Already tried to use ajax it's thow me cross domain error so can not be able to use ajax

Comment: If you're getting a cross domain error then what you're attempting to do is not possible from client-side JS

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqDo2L-aSGw
here is the demo tutorial of appscript ajax call 
and this is source code url : https://www.crazycodersclub.com/appscript/crud-operation-on-google-spread-sheet-using-google-app-script-html-jquery/
You can check this and let me know if you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment yet I'll add a reply. If you're experiencing a CORS issue you can try this CORS Proxy:

https://corsproxy.github.io/

It might work but I don't think it could be a definitive solution. In order to get over a CORS (X domain scripting error) your probably need to configure the servers to accept requests from your domain.

Read more about CORS: https://www.maxcdn.com/one/visual-glossary/cors/